# tkinter closes out after a couple seconds

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to make a Christmas countdown timer and i was almost done. i ran this code and it runs for a second and then closes everything with no errors. im not too advanced in python so if i made any stupid errors then thats why. could it be from threading? im really new to threading so it could be that.

heres my code right now.

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time
from math import *
import threading
import datetime
import asyncio
import sys
root = Tk()
sys.setrecursionlimit(int(10e+6))
    

grid_placeholder = Label(root, text = "                                         ", font=("Arial", 20))
grid_placeholder.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
seconds_check = "" 

def xm(): 

    dt = datetime.datetime
    now = dt.now()
    xmas_days = dt(year = 2021, month = 12, day = 25) - dt(year=now.year, month=now.month, day=now.day, hour=now.hour, minute=now.minute, second=now.second)
    
    string_xmas1 = ""
    string_xmas1 = string_xmas1 + str(xmas_days)

    
    hours = string_xmas1.rsplit(':', 2)[0]
    hours = hours + " hours, "
    
    minutes = string_xmas1.rsplit(':', 2)[1]
    minutes = minutes + " minutes, "
    
    seconds = string_xmas1.rsplit(':', 1)[1]
    seconds = seconds + " seconds"
    

    xmas_days = hours + minutes + seconds
    if xmas_days != seconds_check:
    
        display_time = Label(root, text = xmas_days, font=("Arial", 13)) 
        display_time.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        grid_placeholder.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        xmas_days = seconds_check
        xm()

    
    
    else:
        display_time.destroy()
        display_time = Label(root, text = xmas_days, font=("Arial", 13)) 
        display_time.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        grid_placeholder.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        xm()
    
    
        
t1 = threading.Thread(target = xm)
t1.daemon = True


def thread():
    t1.start()

button_time = Button(root, text= 'CLICK FOR COUNTDOWN', command = thread, height = 5, width = 20)
button_time.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It may be caused by maximum level of recursion reached error on `xm()`.

Comment: Threads aren't needed at all for creating a timer. Also, there's no point in calling `xm()` so often. Since you're only displaying time to the second, you only need to run it once a second.

Comment: I don't have trouble with the window closing by itself when I run this code. I do, however, have other trouble, like the countdown being so flickery that it doesn't show, and I had a lot of trouble trying to get the window to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use threads here.

In tkinter you can use `after()` method to call function after some period of time:

```py
def xm(): 

    # calculations and display
    
    root.after(1000, xm)

button_time = Button(root, text= 'CLICK FOR COUNTDOWN', command = xm, height = 5, width = 20)
button_time.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```